# How to separate the sequence of characters (digits) with space

Tags: text-processing

I have this situation:

`my data`:

```
ID01 120120101
ID02 101010101
ID03 210210210
ID04 505052120
```

And I wanted this data: `output`

```
ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
ID02 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
ID03 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
ID04 5 0 5 0 5 2 1 2 0
```

So, I wanted to separate all digits present in second column (*my data*), but the fist column has to stay intact.

For this I tried to created two files: one with ID ($1-file1) and other with the sequence that I wanted to separate with spaces (file2). After I tried :

```
sed -i -- 's//\t/g' file2
```

but I got the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
perl -alne 'print join " ", $F[0], split("", $F[1])' data
ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
ID02 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
ID03 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 0
ID04 5 0 5 0 5 2 1 2 0
```

If you want (fully) tab separated output, change to

```
perl -alne 'print join "\t", $F[0], split("", $F[1])' data
```

or if you want to preserve a tab after the `ID` but space-separate the digits of the second field,

```
perl -alne 'print join "\t", $F[0], join " ", split("", $F[1])' data
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, an empty regex means to reuse the previous one, which in this case you don't have. If you have the columns separated, you could do something like this:

```
sed 's/./& /g' file2
```

(Match any character, then replace back whatever we matched with `&`, and add the space.)

But changing only the second column is easier to do with `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/./, "& ", $2)} 1' data
```

`gsub` is pretty much the same as `s///g` in sed. As far as I can test `awk` does support the empty regex, but that would add an extra space since it also matches before the first digit. (Well, the above also adds an extra space to the end.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not beautiful but it works

```
cat my_data | sed -e 's/./ &/g' -e 's/^ \(.\) \(.\) \(.\) \(.\)  /\1\2\3\4/'
```

The first expression puts a space before all letters. The next removes the spaces from the first part.

You can also make a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read ID NUMBERS; do
    echo $ID$(echo $NUMBERS | sed -e 's/./ &/g')
done
```

and then run

```
cat my_data | ./my_script
```

Answer (score 0):

When you can't use the `s` command with the `g` flag, one approach is to use the `s` command in a loop with the `t` command (a jump conditional to the `s` succeeding).

Here:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\([^ ]\)\([^ ]\{1,\}\)$/\1 \2/;t1'
```

That is replace a non-space followed by a sequence of 1 or more non-spaces at the end of the line with that non-space, a space and that sequence of non-spaces and repeat until it can't substitute. So for each line, it does (here for the first line):

```
ID01 120120101
-> ID01 1 20120101
-> ID01 1 2 0120101
-> ID01 1 2 0 120101
-> ID01 1 2 0 1 20101
-> ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0101
-> ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0 101
-> ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 01
-> ID01 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
at this point the "s" command fails, so "t1" doesn't branch
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\S+$/join " ", split "", $&/e'
```